# convert latitude and longitude value to double

Tags: java, google-maps

I have Code: `LatLng latLng = new LatLng(-7.11231243, 110.45345433);`

How can I take each value latitude and longitude?

I want to convert like this;

`double lat = -7.11231243;
 double lng = 110.45345433;`

Can anyone help, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the class fields directly, they are public

```
double lat = latLng.latitude;
```

see https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng

Answer (score 1):

You can directly get the value of latitude and longitude from LatLng object.
     `public final class LatLng

```
  public final double latitude

  Latitude, in degrees. This value is in the range [-90, 90].

  public final double longitude

  Longitude, in degrees. This value is in the range [-180, 180).`
```

You need to call this :

`double lat = latlng.latitude;
 double lng = latlng.longitude;`